# How can I make the openlayers (4) map not redraw on overflow on edges?

Tags: typescript, openlayers

Currently my map redraws itself on the overflow, like this:

[image]

The shown simple representation of the countries are plain geojson polygons.

However, I want the map to be shown only once, no matter how far you scroll out.

I tried it with an `extent` in the view, `minResolution, maxResolution, min-/maxZoom`, but nothing seems to work.

This is the current view implementation (though I tried different options of course):

```
new View({
        center: proj.fromLonLat([6.131935, 49.611622]),
        zoom: 4,
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 19,
        minResolution: 1024,
        maxResolution: 4096,
        extent: proj.get('EPSG:3857').getExtent()
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data duplication when zoomed out is controlled at the [`source`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html) level using the `wrapX` attribute.

Using the [OL example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html) showing GeoJson data, one would use:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  wrapX:false,
  features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
});
```